# MSSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) as Procedure Parameter and Variable Declaration Disadvantages

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameter-passing, nvarchar, variable-declaration

The question here is simple but although i have searched a lot, i haven't found an answer on the internet..

Is there any disadvantages using nvarchar(max) comparing with nvarchar(n) in procedure parameters and variable declarations ? ( not for storing, just for execution )

let me give an example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prFoo
@pParam1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
@pParam2 NVARCHAR(32)
....
DECLARE @dVariable1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dVariable2 NVARCHAR(32)
....
```

Is there any performance differences between (@pParam1, @dVariable1) and (@pParam2, @dVariable2) ?

Comment: I can't remember a time where I've had a *choice* of which of those data types I might use and would therefore even start considering which would perform better. If you only need up to 32 characters, use the second form. If you need unlimited length text, use `max`.

Comment: you say "not for storing, just for execution". Actually, in case of MAX form, I'd pay attention on network too. Since the string in a unicode `nvarchar(MAX)` could be very large (up to 2GB).

Comment: i'm trying to write a generic function without considiring all the possibilities ( in order to calculate maximum size ) so, that's why i'm asking this @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Comment: both the database file and the database engine are on the same machine and i'm calling procedures on it, so paying attention on network here is pointless. @Alessandro Alpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when i doing this test, i was expecting to see no difference but results has been shocked me

Sharing below the code which i used to test

```
declare @i int = 0
declare @n int = 1000000
declare @memlimit int = 3072

declare @limited NVARCHAR(3072) = ''
declare @unlimited NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

declare @start DATETIME
declare @limitedMS INT
declare @unlimitedMS INT 

-- measure @limited case
set @i = 0
set @start = GETDATE()
while (@i < @n)
begin
    set @limited = @limited + 'a'
    if len(@limited) = @memlimit
    begin
        set @limited = ''
    end

    set @i = @i + 1
end
set @limitedMS = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @start, GETDATE())

-- measure @unlimited case
set @i = 0
set @start = GETDATE()
while (@i < @n)
begin
    set @unlimited = @unlimited + 'a'
    if len(@unlimited) = @memlimit
    begin
        set @unlimited = ''
    end

    set @i = @i + 1
end
set @unlimitedMS = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @start, GETDATE())

select @limitedMS as LimitedMS, @unlimitedMS as UnlimitedMS
```

the output is the below

```
LimitedMS   UnlimitedMS
1816        3373
```

as you can see, even if i use @memlimit to limit memory allocation for @unlimited variable, **it still works slower than @limited version**